# Selenium: close tab when image: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"tag name","selector":"body"}

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm using python and selenium with firefox. To reach the pages, I must authenticate, and there are redirects involved to login and following the login (I have that working properly, thankfully). Now I need to save images on these SSL-based pages, so currently I open images (e.g., something.jpg or something.svg) in new tabs and take screenshots, as suggested elsewhere on stackoverflow. However, when Firefox loads an image in a tab, such as .SVG, there is no "body" element to find and thus I get an error (Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"tag name","selector":"body"}) when trying

```
body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
```

Question: How can I close these image tabs?

Comment: Hi can you provide the HTML  page source when you use firefox?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I should *not* be using tabs, since Selenium support for them is limited. Instead, I should use Selenium's window handler to open and close different URLs. That worked far more reliably, especially as follows:

```
# open current window
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])

# open last window
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])
```